# Backup File Script

Tags: python, backup

I am writing a script to backup files from one dir(Master) to another dir(Clone).
And the script will monitor the two directories.

If a file inside clone is missing then the script will copy the missing file from Master to 
Clone.Now I have a problem creating the missing folder.

I have read the documentation and found that shutil.copyfile will create a dir if the
dir doesn't exist.But I am getting an IOError message showing that the destination dir
is not exist.Below is the code.

```
import os,shutil,hashlib
master="C:\Users\Will Yan\Desktop\Master"
client="D:\Clone"

if(os.path.exists(client)):
    print "PATH EXISTS"  
else:
    print "PATH Doesn't exists copying"
    shutil.copytree(master,client)
def walkLocation(location,option):
    aList = []
    for(path,dirs,files) in os.walk(location):
        for i in files:
            if option == "path":
                aList.append(path+"/"+i)
            else:
                aList.append(i)
    return aList

def getPaths(location):
    paths=[]
    files=[]
    result =[]
    paths = walkLocation(location,'path')
    files = walkLocation(location,'files')
    result.append(paths)
    result.append(files)
    return result
ma=walkLocation(master,"path")
cl=walkLocation(client,"path")
maf=walkLocation(master,"a")
clf=walkLocation(client,"a")
for i in range(len(ma)):
    count = 0
    for j in range(len(cl)):
       if maf[i]==clf[j]:
           break
       else:
           count= count+1
    if count==len(cl):
        dirStep1=ma[i][ma[i].find("Master")::]
        dirStep2=dirStep1.replace("Master",client)
        shutil.copyfile(ma[i],dirStep2)
```

Can anyone tell me where did I do wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Might it not be easier to use rsync or robocopy

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but the documentation doesn't say that. Here's a reproduction of the [full documentation for the function](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil#shutil.copyfile):

> `shutil.copyfile(src, dst)`
>
> Copy the
>   contents (no metadata) of the file
>   named `src` to a file named `dst`. `dst`
>   must be the complete target file name;
>   look at `copy()` for a copy that accepts
>   a target directory path. If `src` and
>   `dst` are the same files, `Error` is
>   raised. The destination location must
>   be writable; otherwise, an `IOError`
>   exception will be raised. If `dst`
>   already exists, it will be replaced.
>   Special files such as character or
>   block devices and pipes cannot be
>   copied with this function. `src` and `dst`
>   are path names given as strings.

So you have to create the directory yourself.